# Can I combine these three similar functions into a single function?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Can I combine the three very similar functions below into a single function?

All three functions update a particular column in the database. The anonymous object in the update statement is used to update the corresponding column. The member name in the anonymous object should not be changed as it is the name of the column in the database.

I am using ormlite-servicestack for database connection. The DB I use Microsoft SQLServer 2012.

#### Function 1:

```
//Updating the call status.
private void UpdateCallStatus(string claimId, bool isDisconnected)
{
    _LogFactory.LogInfo(this.GetType(), "Updating call status....\n");

    IDbConnectionFactory maConnectionFactory = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
    using (var db = maConnectionFactory.Open())
    {
        db.Update<IVRSCallDetails>(new { IsDisconnected = isDisconnected }, where: callDetail => callDetail.ClaimId == claimId);
    }
}
```

#### Function 2:

```
//Updating the selected dtmf by the client using the claimid.
private void UpdateDtmf(string claimId, string selectedDtmf)
{
    _LogFactory.LogInfo(this.GetType(), "Updating Selected DTMF:" + selectedDtmf + "\n");

    IDbConnectionFactory maConnectionFactory = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
    using (var db = maConnectionFactory.Open())
    {
        db.Update<IVRSCallDetails>(new { SelectedDTMF = selectedDtmf }, where: callDetail => callDetail.ClaimId == claimId);
    }
}
```

#### Function 3:

```
//Updating the isCallMade value..
private void updateIsCallMade(string claimId, bool isCallMade)
{
    _LogFactory.LogInfo(this.GetType(), "Call has been made to the client with claim id: " + claimId + "\n");

    IDbConnectionFactory maConnectionFactoruy = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
    using (var db = maConnectionFactoruy.Open())
    {
        db.Update<IVRSCallDetails>(new { IsCallMade = isCallMade }, where: callDetail => callDetail.ClaimId == claimId);
    }
}
```

Comment: `void CallUpdate<T>(string claimId, dynamic val) { ... db.Update<T>(val, where ... ` ?

Comment: The problem is I have to update the corresponding column in the database.I use anonymous object to map the this object to the corresponding column.But using dynamic won't help here.

Comment: @m.rogalski are you telling  me to pass the anonymous object to the function?

Comment: `new { x = y };` creates an anonymous type. Judging by the code you've showed this "trick" should work but i havent tested it.

Comment: To explain in more details. When you do `new { IsCallMade = isCallMade }` you're creating "object" that is readonly and contains Property/Field named `IsCallMade` with the value of `isCallMade`. Then the mapping procedure should execute that will find `IsCallMade` property and bind it to the adequate column. So calling `void CallUpdate<T>("123", new { IsCallMade = isCallMade });` should do the trick.

Comment: but passing anonymous object to functions are not recommended. But I think this might work. Jamiec provided a better solution to this i guess.

Comment: The thing is.. that you're already doing that in `Update<>()` method. So I don't think that it would make any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change it to a generic method (to be able to pass the type) and also a `Func<object>` in place of the second parameter to generate the anonymous object.

```
private void updateData<T>(string claimId, Func<object> data)
{
    _LogFactory.LogInfo(this.GetType(), "Call has been made to the client with claim id: " + claimId + "\n");

    IDbConnectionFactory maConnectionFactoruy = new DatabaseConnection().getConnection();
    using (var db = maConnectionFactoruy.Open())
    {
        db.Update<T>(data(), where: callDetail => callDetail.ClaimId == claimId);
    }
}
```

usage

```
updateData<IVRSCallDetails>("123", () => new { IsCallMade = true});
updateData<IVRSCallDetails>("123", () => new { SelectedDTMF = selectedDtmf});
```

Comment: what does that Func in function header? Where should I learn about that?   @Jamiec

Comment: For clarity of the rest of the code, & to avoid having to write the function each call, I would retain the original three functions & then use Jamiec's generic function inside each - _"private void updateIsCallMade(string claimId, bool isCallMade) { updateData<IVRSCallDetails>(claimId, () => new { IsCallMade = isCallMade}); }"_

Comment: @Prabu `Func<object>` is just a delegate which expects no parameters and returns an untyped `object` - you can use it to define an anonymous object to be passed to your `db.Update` method